# Drag and Drop is limiting to parent in jQuery plus plus

Tags: jquery, jquery++

Here is the code that I am using to implement drag and drop using jQuery++.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="left">
     <div class="ab">1</div>
     <div class="ab">2</div>
     <div class="ab">3</div>
     <div class="ab">4</div>
     <div class="ab">5</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>


$('.ab').on({
  'draginit': function (ev, drag) {
    drag.ghost();
  }
});

$('#right').on({
 "dropover": function (ev, drop, drag) {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
 },
    "dropout": function (ev, drop, drag) {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
 },
    'dropon': function (ev, drop, drag) {
    $(this).append(drag.element.clone(true, true));
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
 }
});
```

But the problem is occurring when I dragging back to the origin after dropping onto right. It is adding scrollbar and dragging inside the container. How can I fix this problem?

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cjcg4/7/

Comment: +1 for exposing me to `jquery++`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jQuery++, but I took a look at your fiddle.

It looks like you're not binding the `dropover`, `dropout`, `dropon` events to your #left div, which you need to if you want it to behave similarly to #right.

As for the scroll, just remove the `overflow:scroll` property from your #right div.

Here's a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/cjcg4/8/.

What's changed:

1. Use selector `$('#right,#left')` to bind the three events above.
2. Remove `overflow:scroll` css property from #right div

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I remove overflow property how do I accommodate the overflow content?

Comment: I checked out the jQuery++ docs: http://donejs.com/docs.html#!jQuery.Drag.prototype.ghost. You can provide a parent element for the ghost element and leave `overflow:scroll` in: http://jsfiddle.net/mnoble01/cjcg4/9/.